# Re-add computer to domain without local admin

Tags: windows-7, windows-server-2008, active-directory

I have this problem that I can't get a Windows 7 computer to re-join a domain. I have no local account enabled on the machine, so I'm trying to re-add it from the domain controller. I add the computer account by the computer's name, but I can't login on the client with a domain user.

What are my options? How can I get the computer back on the domain? The domain controller is running Windows Server 2008, the client is running Windows 7.

Answer (score 2):

**Joining to a domain requires local admin rights - you can't bypass that.**

If the computer is currently not joined to the domain, then the domain controller (DC) doesn't have any control over it.

What you can do is use [Hiren's Boot CD](http://www.hirensbootcd.org/download/) (or the likes of it) to reset and enable one of the local administrator accounts and then join to the domain. The application on Hiren's Boot CD is **Offline NT Password & Registry Editor**. Note: Use the software at your own risk as it is used to modify the system registry.